# jquery function disables all styles on the page

Tags: jquery, jsp

I've got a form

```
<form action="MakeResponseAction.do" method="POST" id="form-response">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="re"><fmt:message key="request_id" /></label> 
            <select id="re" name="requestid">
            <c:forEach items="${requests}" var="requests">
                    <option value="${requests.id}">${requests.id}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            </select> 
            <label for="aclass"><fmt:message key="aclass" /></label> 
            <input type="text" id="aclass" name="classId" /> 
            <label for="beds"><fmt:message key="beds_n" /></label> 
            <input type="text" id="beds" name="beds" /> 
            <label for="days"><fmt:message key="days_n" /></label> 
            <input type="text" id="days" name="days" /> 
            <label for="fio"><fmt:message key="fio" /></label> 
            <input type="text" id="fio" name="fio" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

When user change option in `select` - I want to set new values in `input`. I've written a function

```
$("#re").change(function(){
    var list = ${requests}; //requests - session attribute  
    var items = $("#re").val();     
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {  
        if (list[i].id == $(this).val()) {  
            $("#aclass").val(list[i].classId);  
            $("#beds").val(list[i].beds);  
            $("#days").val(list[i].days);  
            $("#fio").val(list[i].fio);  
            break;  
        }  
    }  
});
```

But when I add it to my page - all styles disappear. I add it like this

```
$(function() {
//some other functions
$("#re").change(function(){
    var list = ${requests};  
    var items = $("#re").val();     
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {  
        if (list[i].id == $(this).val()) {  
            $("#aclass").val(list[i].classId);  
            $("#beds").val(list[i].beds);  
            $("#days").val(list[i].days);  
            $("#fio").val(list[i].fio);  
            break;  
        }  
    }  
});
});
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `${requests};` ? `<fmt:message` ? What languages are we even talking about ?

Comment: Well I found out that problem is in `${requests}`. I just added quotes - and it doesn't disable styles anymore.

Comment: I suggest not mixing Java Expression Language(EL) with JavaScript.

Comment: I have no other ideas how to get session attribute and its items in javascript code